# orderby in WP_query doesn't works

Tags: wp-query, order, sql

I thought that this already works but now I tested it and it seems that it no longer works. 
I have this code:

```
wp_reset_query();
$args=array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'meta_key' => 'info_tab_1',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC'           
);
$info_tab = null;
$info_tab=new WP_Query( $args );
```

`print_r($args);` prints:

```
Array ( 
  [posts_per_page] => 3 
  [meta_key] => info_tab_1 
  [orderby] => meta_value_num 
  [order] => DESC 
)
```

`print_r($info_tab);` prints:

```
WP_Query Object ( 
  [query_vars] => Array ( 
    [posts_per_page] => 3 
    [meta_key] => info_tab_1 
    [orderby] => title 
    [order] => ASC 
    [error] => 
    [m] => 
    [p] => 0 ...
```

Comment: you need to change `'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',` to `'orderby' => 'meta_value',` - [orderby only accepts certain parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)

Comment: @Howdy_McGee no difference. And in meta value info_tab_1 I have int values.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, I get `meta_value_num` correctly preserved in `WP_Query` using your snippet. Check for offending filters, etc.

Comment: @Rarst What kind of filters? WP_Query for this block on this page every time returns order by title and order ASC. I meen that rand, date and etc orderby doesn't works. The same is about DESC/ASC order.. it returns every time ASC

Comment: Unfortunately there is ton of hooks in `WP_Query` where things can mess it up. You can use something like [Query Monitor](http://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) to look into it.

Comment: All ok! There was just a pre_get_post action. I forgot about it and just added one more compore to it ;)